# Create Pivot Table using Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table, openpyxl

Is there a way we can create pivot table in Excel using openpyxl library?
I saw old threads mentioning its not possible, but I saw some documentation about creating one on below link:

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/api/openpyxl.pivot.table.html

Although I cant find any practical example of how to use the information provided in above link.

Comment: You could import data into `pandas`, pivot it and save it...

Comment: @Susensio thank you for your response. But I guess with Pivot created using Pandas, we cannot get options like 'expand/collapse' buttons, row and column totals and other formatting options that we get in Pivot table created within Excel

Comment: It doesn't appear that the pivot support is intended to be used to create pivot tables from scratch, more to allow existing files with pivot tables to load and save correctly. From [issue 1056](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1056/guideline-example-for-using-pivot-package) in the openpyxl BitBucket: "Pivot tables are very complicated and support was mainly added to preserve them in existing files. I do not expect that we will ever provide full documentation of how to create them in code."

Comment: Thanks for response @spaceDog

Answer (score 11):

**It cannot be done.** As mentioned already in the comments and also in the [official docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pivot.html), the pivot module of openpyxl is only there to preserve existing pivots.

I suggest you create a template.xlsx workbook with raw data on one sheet and your pivot table on another one. In the Excel pivot options, you activate *refresh data when opening file*. Then you use openpyxl to: Load this template, update the raw data and save it somewhere.

Excel will update the pivot table content when the file is opened the next time.